# How to download old MrSID Files without Express View plugin

Tags: mrsid

The University of Alabama hosts some [historic maps in MrSID](http://alabamamaps.ua.edu/historicalmaps/soilsurvey/California/california.html) format, which require the LizardTech Express View plugin to download. This plugin is no longer available.

I have asked Extensis how I can view or download these files and was told the format these file are in is "too old" and there is nothing currently available.

I have emailed UA tech support but have not heard back.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: You don't need a plugin to view the maps on their website.  You can also try accessing via a WMS http://cartweb.geography.ua.edu/lizardtech/iserv/ows?request=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 3):

You can request the full file at higher resolution

Example only: **San Diego**

> http://cartweb.geography.ua.edu/lizardtech/iserv/getimage?cat=Special%20Topics&item=Soil%20Surveys%2FCalifornia%2FSan%20Diego%20CA%201915.sid&wid=2048&hei=2048&oif=jpeg&lev=1

You can right click in a web browser and download as jpeg.

Update using google chrome 91
[image]

Jpeg viewable/editable in Adobe Photoshop (22)
[image]

Comment: That link gives me an error message saying "cartweb.geography.ua.edu didn't send any data."

Comment: @DarreninChico not sure on your set up - But in Google Chrome and Adobe Photoshop the link and image works without an issue.

Comment: @DarreninChico - I'm able to access the image via the link @Mapperz♦ gave.  Using Firefox and Irfanview.  However I noted that the text (e.g. in legend) was unreadable.  So I doubled the requested resolution values and then I could read it.  I don't know how to find out the native (max) resolution, though.  Trying a much larger value returned just a "bad request" response.  Also - I would suggest a lossless format like tif rather than jpg, but that's just my preference.